# Why is there no badge or points for the number of times a question has been "favorited?"

Tags: feature-request, badges

Why is there no badge or points for when people "favorite" your question? Or is there, and I just missed it somehow?

Answer (score 8):

There are such badges:

- [Favorite Question](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/badges/38/favorite-question) – silver, question favorited by 25 users.
- [Stellar Question](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/badges/51/stellar-question) – gold, question favorited by 100 users.

Comment: I guess I didn't thoroughly search all the badges. Thanks!